# Parse query containedIn doesn't return any value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

Several days I'm trying to crack why my code doesn't work and everything I've tried doesn't give me any result. Heres the deal:
There is a Booking class that contains userFrom who made booking

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Booking")
        query.whereKey("offer", equalTo: offer.pfObject!)
        if self.typeOfUser == .COOK { //! If user is a Cook
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [PFObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    if let objects = objects {
                        self.bookings = objects
                        self.usersIds = [String]()
                        for object in objects {
                            let userFrom = object.objectForKey("userFrom") as? PFObject
                            let userId = userFrom!.objectId! as String
                            self.usersIds.append(userId)
                        }
                        self.getUserInfoForBooking()

                    } else {
                        print("Something went wrong")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

From every user I get objectId and append it to the [String] array. Then I query users with their IDs

```
    private func getUserInfoForBooking() {
    let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
    userQuery.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: self.usersIds)
    userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [PFObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print(objects!)
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    self.users.append(object)
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            } 
        }
    })
}
```

In this query I always get an empty array.
Whatever I did, whatever I've changed always [] in response :(

Comment: Are you getting anything at  `println(objects)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way to query users

```
let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
```

Because the class name is private. You should be creating the query as

```
let userQuery = PFUser.query()
```